# table inside table, apply css only for the outer

Tags: css

I have a table element that has also a table inside in one cell. (Jquery UI calendar is inside actually)

How can I style only the parent?

```
body table tr td:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

does this: ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rL667v3k/))

[image: example]

but I would like only the **outer** cells (number 2 and 5) to be selected.

Comment: Can't you just add a special class for those tables? http://jsfiddle.net/q5t5t5um/

Comment: that one selects 7 and A cells

Comment: Whoops, sorry didn't mean to hit enter so quick - something like http://jsfiddle.net/bzosabdz/ ?

Comment: True, I misread the question! Many people has answered with a correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [child (`>`) selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) and add a tbody element in the selector (no HTML changes needed):

```
body > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rL667v3k/8/)**

This works because it specifically only selects the outer table. 
Tested successfully in Chrome, FF, and IE.

Comment: That was my idea too. Can you explain to me why your code works, and `body > table > tr > td:nth-child(2n) { ... }` doesn't? The `tbody` isn't declared in the HTML code, is it automatically rendered?

Comment: @LinkinTED - "is it automatically rendered?" Yup.

Comment: Thank you, and a +1 for stealing my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS:

```
table table tr td:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This selects the cells, but only if they have two `table` parents, and sets their `background-color` to `transparent`.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ku8aj41/)</kbd>

Comment: Just to be clear, if someone wants to use this solution: It should be "if they have AT LEAST two `table` parents". :) Nice solution btw :)

Answer (score 0):

This works, just reset the background for the inner table.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
            <table class="inner">
                <tr><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
                <tr><td>9</td><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

table {
    border-spacing: 2px;}
td{
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}

body table tr td:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: red;
}
body .inner tr td:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: white;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ef1u2umo/)